# undo last git add -A

Tags: git

I accidentally ran 'git add -A'

I haven't run a commit since adding those files and I'd like to undo this command.

I realize that I could manually remove files with

```
git rm --cached <path_to_file>
```

However several files have been  added since and it would be a lot easier to do something like

```
git rm --cached <path_to_file> -A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reset to HEAD will undo it:

```
git reset HEAD
```